# Trying to iterate through a dict linked in another dict from a Python API

Tags: python, django, api, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to get data out of this API endpoint. It is the Sportsipy API.
In the Boxscores endpoint it returns a dictionary of a list of games with basic info, one of the values in that dictionary is a list to 'boxscore' which has all the stats from that individual game.

When I try dot notation it just returns an error saying the dict has no attribute boxscore. If I try a for loop it says its not iterable.

Source Code
'Boxscores' endpoint which then links to the 'boxscore' endpoint.
[Boxscore](https://sportsipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sportsipy/ncaab/boxscore.html#Boxscore)
[Boxscores](https://sportsipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sportsipy/ncaab/boxscore.html#Boxscores)

```py
    import requests
    from django.shortcuts import render    
    from datetime import datetime
    from sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore import Boxscore
    from sportsipy.ncaab.boxscore import Boxscores


    def management(request):
        games = Boxscores(datetime(2021, 2, 13))
        # See output below (partial and re-formatted)
        print(games.games) 
        print(games.games['2-13-2021'][0]['boxscore'])
        # Below - Error: dict has no attribute 'boxscore'
        print(games.games.boxscore) 

        context = {
            'games': games
        }

        return render(request, 'management/management.html', context)
```

```
    print(games.games)
    {'2-13-2021': [{'boxscore': '2021-02-13-18-san-francisco', 
    'away_name': 'Gonzaga', 'away_abbr': 'gonzaga', 'away_score': 100, 
    'away_rank': 1, 'home_name': 'San Francisco', 'home_abbr': 'san- 
    francisco', 'home_score': 61, 'home_rank': None, 'non_di': False, 
    'top_25': True, 'winning_name': 'Gonzaga', 'winning_abbr': 'gonzaga', 
    'losing_name': 'San Francisco', 'losing_abbr': 'san-francisco'}, 
    {'boxscore': '2021-02-13-12-ohio-state', 'away_name': 'Indiana', 
    'away_abbr': 'indiana', 'away_score': 59, 'away_rank': None, 
    'home_name': 'Ohio State', 'home_abbr': 'ohio-state', 'home_score': 
    78, 'home_rank': 4, 'non_di': False, 'top_25': True, 'winning_name': 
    'Ohio State', 'winning_abbr': 'ohio-state', 'losing_name': 'Indiana', 
    'losing_abbr': 'indiana'},
```

Comment: If it's a dict, you probably should try `games.games["boxscore"]`. This is not javascript ;-)

Comment: I try that and I get a key error 'boxscore'

Comment: Please provide output of `print(games.games)`. This might be of help determining what the issue really is.

Comment: uploaded a screenshot of print(games.games)

Comment: The screenshot does not provide the start of the structure, but it looks like the `boxcore` key is packaged in a list. Try `games.games['2-13-2021'][0]['boxscore']`. Also, could you try to capture part of the output in a source code paragraph in your question, instead of a screenshot? For that output, could you use the `pprint` standard library?

Comment: key error '2021, 2, 13'

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to make it runnable, and added the suggested `print` statement.

Comment: For some reason it is just printing the link and not the actual boxscore. For instance, through the 'Schedule' class they have boxscore nested in their dict as well and in my template I can do a for loop and get each stat with dot notation. If I try to do a for loop with the 'Boxscores' class in my template it says Boxcores is not iterable.

Comment: You have to access the date before you can even see the list which contains the dictionary, and what you are looking for is in the dictionary.